# Transition name of textarea or input variable to div

Tags: html, text

When a user writes a name in textarea or input I want him to go to div

Example

< textarea class=""> </ textarea>

When someone says write a name in textarea I want the name to go in place of the word here in div

Is that possible?

< div class="text text-1"> here </ div>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Javascript, I used input with type text instead of textarea, when you type in that input something and press enter what you typed there will be displayed in that div, more exactly in that `<p>` tag.

Also you can add a button next to input which says 'Submit' or something like that, the button need to be in the `<form>` tag.

```js
let text = document.querySelector("#name");
let form = document.querySelector("#form");
let newName = document.querySelector("#newName");
    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); // this line of code will prevent refreshing browser when you submit ( enter is pressed )
        newName.innerHTML = `Your name: ${text.value}`;
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p id="newName">Type your name down below </p>
    </div>
    <form id="form">
        <input id="name" type="text"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```